# What is the efficient way to split a vector

Tags: c++, vector

Is there any other constant time way to split a vector other than using the following.

```
 std::vector<int> v_SplitVector(start , end);
```

This would take a complexity of O(N). In this case O(end - start). Is there a constant time operation to do this.

**OR** am I using the wrong container for the task?..

Comment: Is this a declaration of a function? Please be more precise on your question and provide some more information.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe you can use two pairs of iterators instead.

Comment: provide more information as `v_SplitVector` function is not clear. How u r measuring the complexity?

Comment: I want to split a big vector into smaller vectors. For example 1000000 size vector into 1000 size vectors.

Comment: @Zeus What *Peter* wanted to clarify is, that you should think if you really need the individual vectors or if it would be enough for you to know the ranges of those in the original vector and you could just reference the elements from the original vector with appropriate iterator ranges (since most algorithms don't care about the actual container anyway, only if you need to resize it).

Comment: *"am I using the wrong container for the task?"* - Hard to say without knowing the task. I'm sure you don't just get a vector out of nothing, want to split it and then watch how nice those splits look.

Comment: For example: if you have some functions that do non-resizing operations on a vector, and the reason you want to split the big vector is in order to operate just on the first 1000 elements of it, then the fix is to change the functions to take a pair of iterators instead of taking a vector.

Comment: @ChristianRau I think it's better to keep the reference points of the original vector rather than keeping copies. Then I think I can extract the vector from references to carry out the task. Thanks for clarifying me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The act of "*splitting*" a container, for container like vectors, where elements sits on contiguous memory, require necessarily a copy / move of everything needs to go on the other side.

Container like `list`, that have elements each on its own memory block can be easily rearranged (see `std::list::splice`)

But having elements in non contiguous memory may result in lower memory access performance due to more frequent cache missing.

In other words, the complexity of the algorithm may be not the only factor influencing performance: an infrequent linear copy may *damage* you less than a frequent linear walk on dispersed elements.

The trade-off mostly depends on how the hardware manage caches and how the std implementation you are using takes care of that (and how the compiler can eventually optimize)

Answer (score 3):

This is a copy rather than a split, hence the complexity. You can probably write a split for `list` which might perform better.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` doesn't support the following, but if an efficient "split" operation is very important to you then you could perhaps write your own container. This would be quite a lot of work.

You could define "split" as follows:

- removes an initial segment of the container, and returns a new container containing those elements. References to those elements continue to refer to the same elements in the new container. The old container contains the remaining elements. The capacity of the new container is equal to its size, and the capacity of the old container is reduced by the number of elements removed.

Then the old container and the new container would share a block of underlying storage (presumably with ref-counting). The new container would have to reallocate if you append to it (since the memory immediately at the end of its elements is in use), but so long as that happens rarely or never it could be a win.

Your example code takes a copy, though, it doesn't modify the original container. If a logical copy is a requirement then to do it without actually copying the elements you need either COW or immutable objects.

`std::list` has a `splice()` function that can move a range of elements from one list to another. This avoids copying the elements, but as of C++11 it is in effect guaranteed not to be `O(1)`, because it needs to count how many elements it has moved. In C++03 implementations could choose whether they wanted this op to be `O(1)` or `list::size()` to be `O(1)`, but in C++11 `size()` is required to be constant time for all containers.

Comparing the performance of `std::vector` with `std::list` is usually about more than just one operation, though. You have to consider that `list` doesn't have random-access iterators, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I think it's really quite a lot of work. I think it's better to keep the references instead keeping a copy of a whole vector.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new `std::vector` necessarily requires copying, since
vectors aren't allowed to share parts of their implementation.
A modification in the container from which you obtained `start`
and `end` shouldn't affect the values in `splitVector`.

What you can do, fairly easily, is create a `View` container,
which simply holds the two iterators, and maps all accesses
through them.  Something along the lines of:

```
template <typename Iterator>
class View
{
    Iterator myBegin;
    Iterator myEnd;
public:
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;
    //  And the other usual typedefs, including...
    typedef Iterator iterator;

    View( Iterator begin, Iterator end )
        : myBegin( begin )
        , myEnd( end )
    {
    }

    iterator begin() { return myBegin; }
    iterator end()   { return myEnd; }
    value_type operator[]( ptrdiff_t index ) { return *(myBegin + index ); }
    //  ...
};
```

This requires a fair amount of boilerplate, because the
interface to something like vector is rather complete, but it's
all very straight forward and simple.  The one thing you cannot
do with this, however, is modify the topology of either the
underlying container or of any `View`—anything which might
invalidate any iterators will of course, wreck havoc.

Answer (score 0):

When adding or removing elements to/from a place different than start/end, the vector *must* have complexity of at least o(n) due to internal shifts required. The sme follows when you want to not only remove, but move the elements out: for a vector, they must be copied, hence, at least 1 op per element moved. That means that moving elements out of a vector is at least O(N) where N is the amount of elements moved.

If you need near-constant time add/remove operations (be it adding/inserting one, or many elements) you should look at list/linkedlist containers, where all elements and sublists are easily 'detachable', especially if you know the pointer/iterator. Or trees, or any other dynamic structure.

completely by the way, I sense what `v_SplitVector` does, but where did it came from? I do not remember such function/method in stdlib or boost?

Comment: It's an object being created with iterators.